# Point of zero gravity for fixed masses?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, equilibrium

Given a number of fixed point masses in 3D space, is there necessarily 
one or more points where there is zero gravity (ie, the combined 
gravity of the masses cancels out), and, if so, how do I find it?
Thoughts/questions:

- By continuity, it seems like such a point must exist.
- In general, is there only 1 such point or multiple such points?
- I'm familiar with the Lagrangian point for two bodies, but is 
  there a similar concept for 3+ bodies?
- I tried googling this, but wasn't sure exactly what to google, so 
  got nothing useful.
- I originally thought that the system's barycenter might be this 
  point, but the barycenter is closer to heavier masses (and is also a 
  linear, not $r^{-2}$ combination of the mass points), so it probably 
  experiences more gravity, not less.
- Now suppose the point masses have 0 initial velocity and start to 
  move under the influence of each other's gravity. What happens to 
  the "zero gravity" point(s)?
- Same question, except that the point masses have specific given 
  initial velocities.
- In our solar system (for example), is there anything "interesting" 
  about such points, or are they just a mathematical curiosity?

Comment: If you posit a static system, then it's pretty easy to sum up the various $\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$ to find a null point.  Trouble is, the bodies keep moving and then there's no solution.

Comment: Is there a "simple" formula involving the coordinates of the original points? I can see solving the equation for where force equals zero, but I think it would be fairly ugly. I'm hoping there's some sort of symmetry principle here.